# Counting occurrence of each character in string C++

Tags: c++

So i wanted to count all the characters in a string and categorized them in vowels, consonants, and specials character. For example;

Enter string: sentence example ..

Vowels: e(5) a(1)

Consonants: s(1) n(1) t(1) c(1) x(1) m(1) p(1) l(1)

Specials: blank space .(2)

Here's coding:

```
void characterType(string input)
{
    int vowel = 0;
    int consonant = 0;
    int special = 0;
    int n = input.size();
    int freq[26];
    
    memset(freq, 0, sizeof(freq));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        freq[input[i] - 'a']++;
    }
    cout<<"Vowels: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char character = input[i];
        
        if(isalpha(character))
        {
            character = tolower(character);
            
            if (character == 'a' || character == 'e' || character == 'i' || character == 'o' || character == 'u')
            {
                cout<<input[i]<<freq[input[i] - 'a']<<" ";
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Consonants: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char character = input[i];
        
        if(isalpha(character))
        {
            character = tolower(character);
            
            if (character != 'a' || character != 'e' || character != 'i' || character != 'o' || character != 'u')
            {
                cout<<input[i]<<freq[input[i] - 'a']<<" ";
                
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Specials: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char character = input[i];
        
        if(!isalpha(character))
        {
            if(character == ' ')
            {
                cout<<"[black space]"<<freq[input[i] - 'a']<<" ";
            }
            else
                cout<<input[i]<<freq[input[i] - 'a']<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

And heres what ive got so far:

[image]

How do i make it not repeat the same character and why does special characters is not counting?

Comment: can you use `std::unordered_map` ?

Comment: `character != 'a' || character != 'e'` Both `a` and `e` would pass this filter. You want to use `&&` instead of `||`. Consider making a function for `isVowel()` to cut down on duplication. It also makes it simple to say `if (isVowel(character))` or `if (!isVowel(character))`. You also have an issue where the character is not made lowercase before counting the frequency and since special characters would be outside the `a...z` range your array isn't big enough and `special - 'a'` could be negative.

Comment: A period `.` in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) occurs before `a`, so `input[i] - 'a'` is not going to work to count that special character. You may want to use `' '` as the base special char instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you *want* to do this and it's not some type of *assignment*, here's how I would approach the problem, using modern C++ features:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::map<char, std::size_t> occurrance;
    std::string input{"This is A long string with lots of characters in it. AAA$#!#$!^^!   "};
    
    auto is_vowel = [] (char c) -> bool
    {
        auto lc = std::tolower(c);
        return
            c == 'a' ||
            c == 'e' ||
            c == 'i' ||
            c == 'o' ||
            c == 'u';
    };
    
    auto is_special = [] (char c) -> bool
    {
        // use ascii table to find only "non-special characters"
        if(c < '0')            return true;
        if(c > '9' && c < 'A') return true;
        if(c > 'Z' && c < 'a') return true;
        if(c > 'z')            return true;
        
        return false;
    };
    
    auto vowels = std::count_if(
        input.begin(),
        input.end(),
        is_vowel);
        
    auto special = std::count_if(
        input.begin(),
        input.end(),
        is_special);
    
    for(auto c : input)
    {
        occurrance[c] += 1;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Vowels: " << vowels << '\n';
    std::cout << "Special: " << special << '\n';

    for(auto [c, count] : occurrance)
    {
        std::cout << c << " -> " << count << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/YVaDiI

Answer (score 0):

This does the job, although you can make the output prettier... and take the uppercase letters into account.

```
     void printCharWithFreq(string str)
    {
        int v=0, c=0, s=0;
    
        // size of the string 'str'
        int n = str.size();
    
        // 'freq[]' implemented as hash table
        int freq[SIZE];
    
        // initialize all elements of freq[] to 0
        memset(freq, 0, sizeof(freq));
    
        // accumulate freqeuncy of each character in 'str'
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            freq[str[i] - 'a']++;
    
        // traverse 'str' from left to right
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
            // if frequency of character str[i] is not
            // equal to 0
            if (freq[str[i] - 'a'] != 0) {
    
                // print the character along with its
                // frequency
                if(str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o' || str[i] == 'u' ||
                   str[i] == 'A' || str[i] == 'E' || str[i] == 'I' || str[i] == 'O' || str[i] == 'U')
                { cout<<"Vowel: " << str[i] << freq[str[i] - 'a'] << " "<<endl; v+=freq[str[i] - 'a']; }
    
                else if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '.')
                { cout<<"Specials"<<endl; s++; }
    
                else
                {  cout<<"Consonant: " << str[i] << freq[str[i] - 'a'] << " "<<endl; c+=freq[str[i] - 'a']; }
    
                // update frequency of str[i] to 0 so
                // that the same character is not printed
                // again
                freq[str[i] - 'a'] = 0;
            }
        }
        cout<<"Number of vowels: "<<v<<endl;
        cout<<"Number of consonants: "<<c<<endl;
        cout<<"Number of specials "<<s<<endl;
    }
```

Then test it in the main function like

```
 int main() {

    string str = "some text . .";
    printCharWithFreq(str);


    return 0;
    }
```

Basically, frequency is updated so it doesn't print the same character again, as it says in the comments. You also made a mistake in your code where you wrote:

```
character != 'a' || character != 'e' || character != 'i' || character != 'o' || character != 'u'
```

It is a consonant only if the input is different than ALL of the vowels, meaning you have to put &&, not ||.
As for the special characters, they can be counted with a simple counter.
The rest, I think, is clear from the comments in the code.
I adapted the code from the following source:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-characters-frequencies-order-occurrence/